# working with Facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have seen widgets and apps that show you status updates of your friends on facebook. Does anyone know if it is possible via a custom app to comment or like things from an app or is there no public API for functions of this nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at http://developers.facebook.com and that has all of the API documents you should need (look at Graph API, if that doesn't have it look at the legacy REST API). If there's something missing, request it using the bugzilla on that website.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have an SDK for Android, which your app can use to integrate with Facebook, and do the things you're describing

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk